# Bedeutung von "Irgendwie Glück oder Zufall"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Aus dem *Spiegel-Magazin*:

> Ermittler gaben später zu, dass David vielleicht noch leben würde, hätten sie ihn besser observiert. Aber auch alarmierte Eltern haben kaum eine Chance. Wenn das Kind gehen will, dann geht es. **Irgendwie Glück oder Zufall**, ob sie ihre Söhne an den Krieg verlieren. Glück oder Zufall, ob es einer von ihnen wieder zurückschafft.

Was bedeutet "Irgendwie Glück oder Zufall"? Heißt es gewissermaßen

> Es hängt viel von Glück ab, ob sie ihre Söhne ...

?

Ich verstehe auch nicht, warum beide *Glück* und *Zufall* benannt werden, denn ich finde die beiden fast dasselbe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zur ersten Frage, was bedeutet "Irgendwie Glück oder Zufall"?

Es ist eine Verkürzung von

> **Es ist** irgendwie Glück oder Zufall, ob sie ihre Söhne an den Krieg verlieren.

Wörtlich ins Englische übersetzt:

> It is somehow luck or happenstance whether they lose their sons to the war.

Zur Ähnlichkeit von Glück und Zufall siehe die Antwort von Robert.

Zu dem **irgendwie**: Dieses Wort wird gebraucht, um auszudrücken,

- dass der Schreiber nicht weiß, welcher genaue Mechanismus der Aussage zugrunde liegt (die Eltern verlieren ihre Kinder *irgendwie* an den Krieg, und es hat etwas mit Zufall zu tun)
- oder dass die Worte "Glück" und "Zufall" nicht genau das beschreiben, was der Schreiber meint, aber er im Moment kein besseres Wort findet.

Ein anderes geläufiges Beispiel ist:

> Ich fühle mich irgendwie schlecht.

Das kann wieder heißen, *ich weiß nicht, warum ich mich schlecht fühle* oder *ich fühle mich auf eine Art, die ich im Moment am besten mit "schlecht" bezeichnet kann, aber das trifft es nicht genau*.

Diese Verwendung von "irgendwie" ist leicht umgangssprachlich.

Answer (score 1):

### Glück, Unglück, Pech, oder Zufall.

`Zufall` ist wertneutral und würde in diesem Kontext sicher reichen.

`Glück` eher nicht. Glück ist positiv besetzt und man kann nicht von Glück sprechen wenn man den Sohn an den Krieg verliert. Höchstens von `Pech` oder `Unglück`.

Dass beide genannt werden und auch bei den Sätzen wiederholt werden ist ein Stilmittel und hängt mit der Verwendung von `ob` zusammen. Die Phrase `ob man die Söhne an den Krieg verliert` deckt ja beide Fälle (verlieren und nicht verlieren) ab. Glück, wenn es nicht der Fall ist, Zufall wenn doch.

### Irgendwie

Und da obige Unterscheidungen etwas schwammig sind und man ja eigentlich `Glück, Pech, oder Zufall` schreiben müsste, was etwas zu lang ist, schreibt man einfach ein `irgendwie` davor (siehe Antwort von Georg) :)

Answer (score 0):

Glück und Zufall sind hier sehr ähnlich. Zufall ist random, ohne Wertung. Glück ist positiv besetzt. Wenn wir eine Münze werfen, ist es Zufall, ob sie Kopf oder Zahl zeigt. Wenn ich ein Bier für jedes Mal "Kopf" kriege, ist es Glück, wenn die Münze mit dem Kopf oben liegt.

Comment: Danke, aber meine erste Frage hast Du gar nicht berührt.